# creating a new dataframe from 2 others with columns from the 1st one being the rows of the 2nd one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi i have 2 dataframe in pandas that look like that:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({350 : [100, 101, 99], 
                    250 : [100, 1010, 1020], 
                    210 : [1000, 999, 1000], 
                    200 : [300, 320, 100]}, 
                   index = range(1990, 1993))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [250, 250, 210], 
                    'data' : [100, 1020, 800], 
                    })
```

and I would like to get a new df that looks like:

```
df3

           350    250    210
Date 
1990       100.   1000.  1000
1991       101.   1010.   999
1992       99.    1020.   1000
1993       100.   1020.    800
```

That it adds (if it exists) the df2['data'] column in row of df1 with index that is the last index + 1 (here 1992+1=1993) and the columns of df1 could not match the rows of df2

I hope that's clear and help will be helpful

Comment: `df3 = df1[df2['ID']]`?

Comment: I need to create df3 so it does not exist

Comment: I had a typo check again

Comment: df3 is NaN everywhere

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructors

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the question, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1[list(df2['ID'])],
                 df2.set_index('ID').T
                    .set_axis([df1.index.max()+1])
                    .rename_axis(df1.index.name)
                 ])
```

Output:

```
      350   250   210
Date                 
1990  100  1000  1000
1991  101  1010   999
1992   99  1020  1000
1993  100  1020   800
```

Reproducible inputs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index': [1990, 1991, 1992],
                              'columns': [350, 250, 210, 200],
                              'data': [[100, 1000, 1000, 300],
                               [101, 1010, 999, 320],
                               [99, 1020, 1000, 100]],
                              'index_names': ['Date'],
                              'column_names': [None]},
                             orient='tight')

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index': [0, 1, 2],
                              'columns': ['ID', 'data'],
                              'data': [[350, 100], [250, 1020], [210, 800]],
                              'index_names': [None],
                              'column_names': [None]},
                             orient='tight')
```